# RESTful, a fit for all?

Tags: rest

Does REST architecture fit for all cases?

Consider an example:

```
Person {
    int id;
    String name;
    boolean verified;
}
```

Now, verified is a 'result' of a third-party verification done on the Person.

In pre-REST era I'd write something like this:

```
www.prerest.com/person/verify
```

to get the person verified and update the flag with the result of the 'action'.

How do I write a RESTful, noun based, API for this?

If I do decide to write a verb based API, like the one above, I guess it won't be a RESTful architecture. And would it be called a 'bad idea'?

Answer (score 2):

> Does REST architecture fit for all cases?

Here's Roy T Fielding, [writing in 2008](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven#comment-742)

> REST is intended for long-lived network-based applications that span multiple organizations. If you don’t see a need for the constraints, then don’t use them.

But that doesn't seem to be what you are asking

> In pre-REST era I'd write something like this....

Perfectly fine.  REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your identifiers.  The server has complete discretion to encode information into the identifier for its own exclusive use.

```
www.prerest.com/person/verify
```

Perfectly fine, as far as REST is concerned.  So is

```
wwww.prerest.com/223d17c3-6f6a-42b6-9ddd-599df9811ad4
```

> If I do decide to write a verb based API, like the one above, I guess it won't be a RESTful architecture. And would it be called a 'bad idea'?

If you are worried about the spelling of your URI, it's already not a RESTful architecture, I can promise you that.  See this talk by [Stefan Tilkov](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pspy1H6A3FM).

But if your local style guide calls for using nouns....  Pay attention to the *document* that is being returned by your endpoint.  The "resource" is an *integration* resource -- so what is the name of it?  Are clients integrating with a verification token?  a claim check?  a report?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like verification is a potentially longer running process.

One way to model this is to introduce a `verification` resource, use POST to create one and end up with a `Location` of the verification result or a resource that allows you to discover the verification result when it is available.

```
POST /person/123/verification
--> Location: /person/123/verification/456
```